# Comparing Two Arrays Without Using -Compare

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting, match

I have two array's, one contains multiple columns from a CSV file read in, and the other just contains server names, both type string. For this comparison, I plan on only using the name column from the CSV file. I don't want to use `-compare` because I want to still be able to use all CSV columns with the results. Here is an example of data from each array.

csvFile.Name:

```
linu40944
windo2094
windo4556
```

compareFile:

```
linu40944
windo2094
linu24455
```

As you can see, they contain similar server names, except `$csvFile.Name` contains 25,000+ records, and `$compareFile` contains only 3,500.

I've tried:

```
foreach ($server in $compareFile) {
    if ($csvFile.Name -like $server) {
        $count++
    }
}
```

Every time I run this, it takes forever to run, and results in `$count` having a value in the millions when it should be roughly 3,000. I've tried different variations of `-match`, `-eq`, etc. where `-like` is. Also note that my end goal is to do something else where `$count` is, but for now I'm just trying to make sure it is outputting as much as it should, which it is not.

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I using the wrong formatting?

Answer (score 2):

One possible thought given the size of your data.

Create a hashtable (dictionary) for every name in the first/larger file.  Name is the Key. Value is 0 for each.

For each name in your second/smaller/compare file, add 1 to the value in your hashtable IF it exists.  If it does not exist, what is your plan???

Afterwards, you can dump all keys and values and see which ones are 0, 1, or >1 which may or may not be of value to you.

If you need help with this code, I may be able to edit my answer.  Since you are new, to StackOverflow, perhaps you want to try this first yourself.

Comment: Hashtables are the way to go for huge compare operations, they are indeed very fast for compare operations.

Comment: Wow, so much faster than what I was going to suggest (regex match on name, 25k objects/3.5k strings, average time to compute was 19.5 seconds on 100 tries), and faster than `Compare-Object` (average time to compute was 14 seconds). Even when I reversed it, made the hashtable with the short list, and ran the larger list like `$compareFile | Where{$RefHT.ContainsKey($_.Name)}` this only took 1 second on average to complete. Crazy fast compared to the others! I reversed the hashtable to get similar output to the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Build custom objects from `$compareFile` (so that you can compare the same property), then use `Compare-Object` with the parameter `-PassThru` for the comparison. Discriminate the results using the SideIndicator.

```
$ref = $compareFile | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Name' = $_
    }
}

Compare-Object $csvFile $ref -Property Name -PassThru | Where-Object {
    $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='
} | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude SideIndicator
```

The trailing `Select-Object` removes the additional property `SideIndicator` that `Compare-Object` adds to the result.